# Como é possível inserir no banco mysql uma string contendo o caracter *

Tags: php, mysql

Estou utilizando PHP e Mysql e estou tentando adicionar um campo de ID de rádio tipo NEXTEL e CLARO:

```
23*4567
```

Só que quando verifico o que foi inserido, vejo que só registrou o que está antes do *, ficando assim:

```
23
```

Utilizando uma query normal assim:

```sql
INSERT INTO tabela (id_radio) VALUES ("23*4567")
```

Já tentei utilizar as funções, porém nada funcionou.

```php
addslashes()
mysql_real_scape_string()
```

É necessária alguma função para que o * seja aceito pelo mysql?

Comment: Esse teu campo `id_radio` é de que tipo? `integer`, `decimal`, `varchar` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta trocar o tipo do campo para varchar e inserir como string no campo.

Comment: Perfeito meu amigo! Quebrei a cabeça o dia inteiro para simplesmente resolver dessa forma tão simples.

Answer (score 1):

Se você usar uma [query parametrizada](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) o banco vai conseguir inserir caracteres especiais sem problema algum. Só é preciso escapar os valores se você estiver criando a query na mão, com literais fixos.

```
//$dbh é a sua conexão com o BD.
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela (id_radio) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->execute(array("23*4567"))
```

Comment: A ideia é boa meu amigo, porém eu não sei absolutamente nada de php orientado =/. Até tentei mas ficou dando um erro louco atrás do outro e eu desiste.

Comment: Uma API com consultas preparadas e parâmetros separados é mais robusta e segura do que uma API baseada em escapamento de strings, independentemente de se ela é implementada com objetos ou não. Persevere :)

Answer (score 1):

Se o campo que possui o número do rádio for numerico(int, float, numeric) troque ele para para `varchar`, isso também elimina o problema de algum número que começa com zero pois eles são removidos quando estão a esquerda.

O código para alter o tipo de coluna é esse:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela MODIFY  campo varchar(50)
```

Fiz um teste crie um tabela com duas colunas e executei esse insert direto no banco

```
INSERT INTO radios(radio_int, radio_varchar) values(23*4567, '23*4567')
```

o resultado foi

```
radio_int: 105041
radio_varchar: 23*4567
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente enviar o char do carácter * ao invés do carácter em si por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (id_radio) VALUES ("23".CHAR(42)."4567")
```